How did I mess up my .pickle? I'm getting an "EOFError: Ran out of input" error, but the file isn't empty. Where did my loop fail?
I have a python script which iterates through all of the videos in a directory and performs inference using a neural network to classify segments of the videos, and saves the inference results to a database which is saved as a pickle file. The idea each loop is to:

Open the existing pickle file

Assign its contents to a dictionary (ShotDB)

Perform inference

Append the results to the dictionary

Save the updated dictionary as a pickle (overwrite the original)


Somehow, I've messed up my pickle file such that when I try to load it subsequent times, I get an end of file error, and I'm not sure why.
As for my code, this part runs at the start of the script to load ShotDB:
# Check if ShotDB already exists in the output directory
existing_shotdb_path = os.path.join(output_directory, "shotdb.pkl")
if os.path.exists(existing_shotdb_path):
    print("Loading existing ShotDB...")
    with open(existing_shotdb_path, "rb") as f:
        ShotDB = pickle.load(f)
else:
    ShotDB = {}

Then, for my main loop, I have:
# Main loop to process each video in the input directories
for video_path in video_files:
    # Skip files that have already been processed
    if video_path in ShotDB:
        print(f"Skipping already processed video: {video_path}")
        progress_bar_main.update(1)
        continue

    # Process the video and update ShotDB
    process_video(video_path, ShotDB)

    # Save ShotDB after processing each video
    with open(existing_shotdb_path, "wb") as f:
        pickle.dump(ShotDB, f)

    # Update the progress bar
    progress_bar_main.update(1)

If it helps, here's the process_video() function:
# Function to process a video file
def process_video(video_path, ShotDB, debug = False):
    try:
        # Check video height
        video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(video_path)
        video_height = int(video_capture.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))
        total_frames = int(video_capture.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))
        video_capture.release()

        if video_height < minimum_video_height:
            print(f"Skipping video {video_path} due to insufficient height ({video_height} pixels).")
            return

        print(f"\nProcessing video: {video_path}")

        # Initialize variables
        inference_results = {}
        no_improvement_counter = 0
        reset_counter = False  # Initialize reset_counter here

        # Initialize variables to keep track of the best maximum probabilities for each category
        best_max_probabilities = [0] * num_categories

        # Loop until patience is reached
        while no_improvement_counter < patience:
            if debug:
                print(f"\nNo improvement counter: {no_improvement_counter} / {patience}")

            # Randomly sample a start frame
            start_frame = np.random.randint(0, total_frames - num_frames*2)
            if debug:
                print(f"Start frame: {start_frame}, (0, {total_frames - num_frames*2})")

            # Initialize list to store inference results for sampled frame and surrounding frames
            all_predictions = []

            # Iterate over frame offsets
            for offset in [-num_frames, 0, num_frames]:
            #for offset in [0]:
                if debug:
                    print(f"Start Frame + Offset: {start_frame+offset}")
                # Get frames from the video
                frames = get_frames(video_path, start_frame=start_frame+offset, num_frames=num_frames, target_height=target_height, background_subtraction=background_subtraction, debug=False)

                # Check if frames is None
                if frames is None:
                    print(f"Error reading frames for video: {video_path}")
                    return

                # Convert frames to a numpy array
                frames_array = np.array(frames)

                # Reshape frames to match the input shape expected by the model
                frames_array = np.expand_dims(frames_array, axis=0)  # Add batch dimension

                # Perform inference with verbose=0
                predictions = model.predict(frames_array, verbose=0)
                if debug:
                    print(f"Predictions: {predictions}")

                # Store inference results
                all_predictions.append(predictions[0])

            # Average the predictions
            averaged_predictions = np.mean(all_predictions, axis=0)
            if debug:
                print(f"Averaged predictions: {averaged_predictions}")
                print(f"Best max probabilities: {best_max_probabilities}")

            # Update the best maximum probabilities for each category
            for category_index in range(num_categories):
                if averaged_predictions[category_index] > best_max_probabilities[category_index]:
                    best_max_probabilities[category_index] = averaged_predictions[category_index]
                    reset_counter = True
                    if debug:
                        print(f"Updated best max probabilities for category {category_index}: {best_max_probabilities[category_index]}")

            # Store inference results for the current start frame
            inference_results[start_frame] = averaged_predictions

            # Increment no_improvement_counter if needed
            if reset_counter:
                no_improvement_counter = 0
                reset_counter = False
            else:
                no_improvement_counter += 1

        # Update ShotDB with inference results for this video
        print(f"Adding {len(inference_results)} entries.")
        ShotDB[video_path] = inference_results

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error processing video: {video_path}. {e}")

Here's the error that happened:
Processing video: F:\Footage\oJnM30dO.mp4
[ WARN:0@87066.444] global cap_ffmpeg.cpp:441 cv_capture_retrieve FFmpeg: Exception is raised: OpenCV(4.9.0-pre) /build/opencv/modules/core/src/alloc.cpp:73: error: (-4:Insufficient memory) Failed to allocate 2764800 bytes in function 'OutOfMemoryError'

Error processing video: F:\Footage\oJnM30dO.mp4. Graph execution error:

Detected at node 'sequential/time_distributed/Reshape_1' defined at (most recent call last):
    File "c:\Python\ShotDB_Creator.py", line 171, in <module>
      process_video(video_path, ShotDB)
    File "c:\Python\ShotDB_Creator.py", line 91, in process_video
      predictions = model.predict(frames_array, verbose=0)
    File "C:\Users\thuhg\miniconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 65, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "C:\Users\thuhg\miniconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 2253, in predict
      tmp_batch_outputs = self.predict_function(iterator)
    File "C:\Users\thuhg\miniconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 2041, in predict_function
      return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "C:\Users\thuhg\miniconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 2027, in step_function
      outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "C:\Users\thuhg\miniconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 2015, in run_step
      outputs = model.predict_step(data)
    File "C:\Users\thuhg\miniconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1983, in predict_step
      return self(x, training=False)
    File "C:\Users\thuhg\miniconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 65, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "C:\Users\thuhg\miniconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 557, in __call__
      return super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)
    File "C:\Users\thuhg\miniconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 65, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "C:\Users\thuhg\miniconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 1097, in __call__
      outputs = call_fn(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    File "C:\Users\thuhg\miniconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 96, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "C:\Users\thuhg\miniconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\sequential.py", line 410, in call
      return super().call(inputs, training=training, mask=mask)
    File "C:\Users\thuhg\miniconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\functional.py", line 510, in call
      return self._run_internal_graph(inputs, training=training, mask=mask)
    File "C:\Users\thuhg\miniconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\functional.py", line 667, in _run_internal_graph
      outputs = node.layer(*args, **kwargs)
    File "C:\Users\thuhg\miniconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 65, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "C:\Users\thuhg\miniconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 1097, in __call__
      outputs = call_fn(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    File "C:\Users\thuhg\miniconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 96, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "C:\Users\thuhg\miniconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\keras\layers\rnn\time_distributed.py", line 264, in call
      y = tf.__internal__.nest.map_structure_up_to(
Node: 'sequential/time_distributed/Reshape_1'
Input to reshape is a tensor with 107520 values, but the requested shape requires a multiple of 268800
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Python\ShotDB_Creator.py", line 175, in <module>
    pickle.dump(ShotDB, f)
MemoryError
Processing Videos:  16%|███████████████████████████▉                                                                                                                                                      | 1130/7214 [24:11:11<130:13:17, 77.05s/it]

So, presumably, I had an out of memory error, and now somehow I've messed up my pickle file. Now, when I try to run the script subsequent (after removing the offending file), I get this EOFError and cannot open the pickle:
PS C:\Python> & C:/Users/thuhg/miniconda3/envs/tf/python.exe c:/Python/ShotDB_Creator.py
Number of categories: 9
Loading existing ShotDB...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Python\ShotDB_Creator.py", line 134, in <module>
    ShotDB = pickle.load(f)
EOFError: Ran out of input

From what I can gather, it sounds like there's been some type of issue saving the pickle file. The file is not empty--it's 8,195 KB, so presumably the data from the previous ShotDB dictionary is still there, but I'm not sure what happened to the file such that now I am getting an end of file error when trying to read it. (I thought that if there was an error updating the ShotDB dictionary, we would break out of the loop and not try to save the pickle).
Any ideas?

if you have standard dictionary in ShotDB then maybe you should keep it as JSON file.

That's a good suggestion. I'd considered that at the start, but I thought that pickles were supposed to be more efficient than JSON the larger the database gets. But if it's easier to work with and my database is only 8MB, it's probably not a bad trade-off.
